# PySide 2's Shiboken2 removes paths to original header files

Tags: c++, python-3.x, pyside2

I want to wrap many classes written in **C++** using **PySide 2**'s **shiboken2** in order to be available in **Python**. However there are some issues when trying to wrap more complex code.

I have two different files with two different headers and in different namespaces:

```
#include <gui/main.h>
```

and second one:

```
#include <back/foo.h>
```

This code's scheme is written in **app.xml** to be ready for wrapping:

```
<typesystem package="app">
  <load-typesystem name="typesystem_core.xml" generate="no"/>
  <load-typesystem name="typesystem_widgets.xml" generate="no"/>
  <namespace-type name="gui">
    <object-type name="Main"/>
  </namespace-type>
  <namespace-type name="back">
    <object-type name="Foo"/>
  </namespace-type>
</typesystem>
```

But the wrapped code seems to forget original paths and therefore header files cannot be found:

```
#include <main.h>
#include <foo.h>
```

I am wondering how to fix this. The code of course compiles when I manually copy those file to the folder where the wrap code is; however our app has many headers with the same name and therefore that problem has to be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little help from a developer from **#qt-pyside** I have managed to solve this issue which had bothered me for a while.

```
<typesystem package="app">
    <extra-includes>
        <include file-name="gui/main.h" location="global"/>
        <include file-name="back/foo.h" location="global"/>
    </extra-includes>
    <load-typesystem name="typesystem_core.xml" generate="no"/>
    <load-typesystem name="typesystem_widgets.xml" generate="no"/>
    <namespace-type name="gui">
        <include file-name="gui/main.h" location="global"/>        
        <object-type name="Main">
            <include file-name="gui/main.h" location="global"/>
        </object-type>
    </namespace-type>
    <namespace-type name="back">
        <include file-name="back/foo.h" location="global"/>
        <object-type name="Foo">
            <include file-name="back/foo.h" location="global"/>
        </object-type>
    </namespace-type>
</typesystem>
```

Notice that I have added lines such as:

```
<include file-name="gui/main.h" location="global"/>
```

and

```
<extra-includes>
```

in the beginning.